# Dynamic Equation Editor

Tags: excel, equation

With VBA, I like to create a dynamic visualization of a Equation (using Equation Editor).
To create the graphic formula I suppose I need to find a method to set/get a string like HTML or RTF format. In the string I put some tag to build the graphic part of the equation. STOP !

The same sample is about a single cell in Excel. I can have inside:

```
<pre>
 <p class=MsoNormal>H<b>ell</span></b><h1>o</h1></p>
</pre>
```

If I get value, value2, text I lost the format data. The same about cell format. I can only check all the characters 1 by 1...
If i have a string like HTML or RTF I don't lost nothing.
I hope I have explain better...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm answer (partially) to Myself...
Now I can insert inside a equation object a formula with this code:

```
Sheets(1).Shapes("Textbox 5").DrawingObject.Text = kk
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 5")).Select
SendKeys "a{BS}{ENTER}{ESC}"
DoEvents
Range("A1").Select
```

But:
1) I shall havea Shape with Equation inside.
2) I need to FORCE Equation to be rebuilt usind SendKeys.
I have found some code for building the formula, the others I can found ...

[image]

I have problem with SQRT because I don't know (up to now), how to add UTF-8 char inside a text...
To solve the problem, I have added before this code:

```
Dim kk As String
Dim Tmp As String
kk = ""
Tmp = Range("InputFormula").Value
For e = 1 To Len(Tmp)
    If Mid(Tmp, e, 3) = "{v}" Then
        kk = kk & Range("Radice").Text
        e = e + 2
    Else
        kk = kk & Mid(Tmp, e, 1)
    End If
Next
```

that copy a cell with the UTF-8 code inside...